# Get Microsoft Exchange Authentication token through Android's AccountManager

Tags: android, authentication, exchange-server, single-sign-on, activesync

I am working on an Android 3.0 program that can connect to a SSL'd php webservice (outputs data in JSON, I can modify the server). The tablets that are connecting to this service have a corporate Microsoft ActiveSync (exchange 2010) account, and only that account (no google accounts,FB, etc). I would like to write a program that can use the credentials saved in the tablet's [android.accounts.AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) to make secure requests on that PHP webservice. I tried following some google examples but I think the problem lies when I use the line:
`AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> data = am.getAuthToken(b, "JWT", options, this, ota, null);`
The application just hangs and I get no results. 
In fact, setting a breakpoint at any line in the OnTokenAcquired class, doesn't do anything. AKA OnTokenRequired never gets executed

Any advice or direction? I'm sure this could be helpful for getting corporate android client software

```
import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.accounts.AccountManagerFuture;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class AcctestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        OnTokenAcquired ota = new OnTokenAcquired(et);
        Account exchange = null;
        Bundle options = new Bundle();
        for(Account a : am.getAccounts()){
              if(a.type.equals("com.android.exchange") && a.name.endsWith("@domain.com"))
                     exchange = a;
        }
        AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> data = am.getAuthToken(exchange, "JWT", options, this, ota, null);
    }
}
```

---

```
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback;
import android.accounts.AccountManagerFuture;
import android.accounts.AuthenticatorException;
import android.accounts.OperationCanceledException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class OnTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {
       private EditText et;
       public OnTokenAcquired(EditText et){
              this.et = et;
       }
       public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
              Bundle bundle;
              try {
                     Toast.makeText(null, "Start!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     bundle = result.getResult(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                     String token = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);                         et.append("\nToken: " + token);
                     Toast.makeText(null, token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
              }            
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of research in the sources I've found this code:

```
public Bundle  getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle loginOptions) throws NetworkErrorException {
     return null;
}
```

This means, the android exchange Authenticator doesn't provide the Tokenbased Authentication for Exchange-Server...

Comment: do you know if this changed in 2016 ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the proper token type for Exchange accounts. I don't know what it is offhand, but I doubt it would be 'test'. Research what the proper token type is (if supported) first. Otherwise your code looks OK. How to authenticate to Exchange using a token is another matter though.

Comment: check EDIT for my response. I couldnt fit all that in here and i posted updated code

Comment: What type of authentication is your PHP service using? And what makes you think that you need a "JWT" token? As it turns out the default Exchange authenticator does not supports tokens, it just returns null.

Comment: hmm.. i started looking through a [couple of the guides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc425499%28v=EXCHG.%2080%29.aspx). [this xoauth guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh745374.aspx) was mainly where i thought to use JWT or something along those lines.
the PHP webservice right now does not use authentication, I am in the process of trying to figure it out. I was thinking of using SSL to encrypt the data to the ssl server with an authentication token so the webservice can keep track of which employee is using the service. So if no authtoken, any idea on how to do SSO?

Comment: I haven't read those, but it can probably be done. Except that the built-in Exchange authenticator doesn't support tokens, and that means you can use `AccountManager`. You'll have to get the tokens using a WebView by logging into whatever login page Exchange provides. If you are using any kind of authentication, do use SSL, but that is not directly related, it just encrypts the communication channel.